# batch renaming script files

Tags: bash, unix, rename

In my nas4free (freeBSD) i have a few directories containing photos, I would use one bash script to rename each file with the name of the directory that contains it and counter.

example:

from

```
/ path/2012-05-01 - description / DSCN4074.JPG
```

to

```
/ path/2012-05-01 - description / 2012-05-01 - description (1 to n). jpg
```

Comment: What is the question?  What have you tried so far?  Are you having a problems with something specific?

Comment: I just finished developing a script. The script works, I do not know if it is correct from the point of view of logic or syntax. #!/bin/bash COUNT=1 echo Sto cercando i file EXT=jpg for FILE in $(find . -type f -iname "*.$EXT") do CURRENT=pwd | cut -d / -f 5 NAME=echo $FILE | cut -d / -f 2 TOT=ls |grep -i "$EXT" | wc -l echo $CURRENT "("$COUNT "di" $TOT").jpg" | xargs -I {} mv "$NAME" "{}" let "COUNT=$COUNT+1"; done exit

Comment: OMG i don't know how to formatting text... sorry

Answer (score 0):

You should count the number of files only once per directory, and reduce piping:

```
#!/bin/bash
EXT=.jpg

shopt -s nullglob
find . -mindepth 2 -type d | while read d
do( cd "$d"
    CURRENT=$(basename "$d")
    FILES=(*"$EXT")
    TOT=${#FILES[@]}
    COUNT=0
    for FILE in ${FILES[@]}
    do  let COUNT=COUNT+1
        mv "$FILE" "$CURRENT ($COUNT of $TOT)$EXT"
    done
)done
```